# Need a help in understanding a solution of a second problem in Israel Gohberg.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, proof-explanation

The problem and its solution is given in these 2 pictures:

[image]

[image]

But I did not understand the following:

1-In the second line in the solution the last equality I do not know how the sum changed from $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=j-1}$ to $\sum_{k=-\infty}^{k=\infty}$ and the value of the sum remained the same, could anyone clarify this for me please?

2-In the solution in the second line from below, the middle term why it is greater than or equal to the first term? I thought that the second term is exactly equalto the first term, am I right?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- For the second line, note that $a_{jr}\alpha_r=0$ when $r\leqslant 0$. Hence $$\sum_{k=-\infty}^{j-1}|a_{j,j-k}\alpha_{j-k}|=\sum_{k=-\infty}^{\infty}|a_{j,j-k}\alpha_{j-k}|.$$
- For the second line from below, for $k<0$, it follows that $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty|\alpha_{j-k}|^2=\sum_{j=1-k}^\infty|\alpha_{j}|^2\leqslant\|x\|^2$$ (recall that the square of the $\ell^2$ norm for $x$ is the absolute square of its coordinates), and the strict inequality holds if some $\alpha_{j_0}\neq 0$ with $j_0<1-k$. Thus the equality may not hold.

Comment: For the second line, why we are sure that the added terms will give us $r \leq 0 $? and hence are zeros?

Comment: @Intuition Note that in this $\ell^2$ space, entries with negative indices of $x=(\alpha_1,\alpha_2,\cdots)$ are naturally regarded as zero. For each added term in the sum of the second line, the index $k$ is larger than $j-1$ and hence $j-k\leqslant 0$. This is where $r\leqslant 0$ comes from.